# Is there a way to get "Dominator Tree"-like functionality from a running JVM?

Tags: jvm, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Recently, I've been digging in to JVM heap dumps using [Eclipse MAT](https://eclipse.org/mat/).  I like it, but the one feature that I seem to use the most is the [Dominator Tree](https://eclipse.org/mat/about/screenshots.php).  Eclipse's example screenshot:

[image: Eclipse Dominator Tree Sample Screenshot]

Anyways, I find that a lot of the time, I usually get the most value out of just looking at that table and getting the first few entries.  Since the turnaround time for getting this is:

1. Create Heap Dump (`jcmd <pid> GC.heap_dump`)
2. Download/Pull heapdump to a location (MAT isn't installed on our servers)
3. Run Eclipse MAT's `ParseHeapDump.sh` tool to build the various trees
4. Open MAT, click **Dominator Tree** icon.
5. Analyze

Is there a way to get this equivalent information off of a **running** JVM programmatically?  I'd like to run some kind of `gather_dominators.sh <pid>` script on a host and get the Top X Objects from a JVM, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: have you looked at the source of the jars used by `ParseHeapDump.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "***running*** jvm" You meant - "*getting the info without doing stop-world heap-dump*" then the obvious answer is: in order to do such thing without "full-scan" - the data needs to be collected throughout system life-time by tapping creation/release of each object and by maintaining the statistics. You could achieve such things by instrumentation or by using a ready-made custom agents (jol/jamm/etc). Note that many GCs are already doing similar work to collect (and print) statistics. IIRC - newer JVMs even keep track of such info within the class-metadata area (so getting statistics is instant).

- https://github.com/google/allocation-instrumenter
  (google-allocation-instumenter)
- http://blog.javabenchmark.org/2013/07/compute-java-object-memory-footprint-at.html (with JAMM)
- https://github.com/jbellis/jamm (JAMM src)
- [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object) (JOL/etc here)
- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074458/core-java/estimating-java-object-sizes-with-instrumentation.html (short DYI guide)
- https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Understanding+Java+GC
  (webCast on how GC traverses objects for similar purposes)

---

On other hand - if You're fine to grab a **heap-dump** (which should be fine on any production system with any proper node-redundancy in place, designed for handling unavoidable Sun-JVM stop-world GC pauses), then Jhat, MAT-api, YourKit and Jol are probably Your best friends:

- [Programmatically analyze java heap dump file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127447/programmatically-analyze-java-heap-dump-file)
- [How to analyse the heap dump using jmap in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130956/how-to-analyse-the-heap-dump-using-jmap-in-java)

It is important to note that currently-existing heap-dump format loses the info about actual sizes of objects, so all tools (MAT/etc) are just *trying to **GUESS*** it properly:

- http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/heapdump-is-a-lie/ (What Heap Dumps Are Lying To You About, by Aleksey Shipilёv)

HTH :)